# Creating a sequence using data.table::rleid with some rows excluded based on additional condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to create a sequence of subsequent, identical values like `data.table::rleid` does. But the issue is that I want some rows to be excluded from the sequence and which rows should be excluded can be defined by another column. I have figured out that `data.table::rleid` can be used twice, but it still doesn't produce the ideal result - see below:

```
my_example <- structure(list(event = c(234, 234, 224, 232, 232, 201, 201, 201, 
201, 201, 201, 201, 244, 244, 201, 201, 201, 244, 244, 212, 201, 
201, 201, 249, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 249, 201, 201, 
244, 244, 201, 261, 245, 203, 204, 204, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 
201, 216, 201), subgroup = c(10L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L,  
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .Names = c("event", "subgroup"))

my_example %>% 
  mutate(in_seq = ! event %in% c(224, 232, 234, 261), 
         seq = data.table::rleid(subgroup) * in_seq,
         seq2 = data.table::rleid(seq))

# A tibble: 50 x 5
    event subgroup in_seq   seq  seq2
    <dbl>    <int> <lgl>  <int> <int>
 1   234       10 F          0     1
 2   234       11 F          0     1
 3   224       10 F          0     1
 4   232       10 F          0     1
 5   232       11 F          0     1
 6   201       10 T          5     2
 7   201       10 T          5     2
 8   201       10 T          5     2
 9   201       10 T          5     2
10   201       10 T          5     2
# ... with 40 more rows
```

How can I exclude some rows from numeration? (In the example above it would mean that rows 1:5 as well as row 38 would have NA in `seq2`)

Comment: Can you show the expeced output?  Based on the example, the 'seq' starts at 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to change the values in 's2' to `NA`

```
library(data.table)
my_example %>% 
  mutate(in_seq = ! event %in% c(224, 232, 234, 261), 
         s1 = rleid(subgroup * in_seq), 
         s2 = rleid(s1) * NA ^ !in_seq)
```

Or if the 's2' needs to start from '1' skipping the `FALSE` in 'in_seq'

```
my_example %>% 
   mutate(in_seq = ! event %in% c(224, 232, 234, 261), 
      s1 = data.table::rleid(subgroup) * in_seq, 
      s2 = (NA^!s1) * s1,
      s2 = match(s2, unique(na.omit(s2))))
```

---

Or it could be

```
setDT(my_example)[, in_seq := !event %in% c(224, 232, 234, 261)
      ][, s1 := rleid(subgroup) * in_seq
       ][s1 != 0, s2 := rleid(s1)]
```

Comment: Not exactly, I would like to still preserve this rows in a data.frame, just exclude from sequence numbering